# escape sequences while importing csv file into list

Tags: python, list, csv, numpy, arraylist

Suppose i have a .csv file which has a row that contains: 
`['overheard', 'everi', 'time', 'movi', 'adapt', 'book', 'announc', 'me', 'i', 'want', 'excit', "i'v"]`

but when I import this row into a list using `corpus=[rows[0] for rows in csvReader1]` the data i get is `'[\'overheard\', \'everi\', \'time\', \'movi\', \'adapt\', \'book\', \'announc\', \'me\', \'i\', \'want\', \'excit\', "i\'v"]'`

it is full of escape sequences

Is there any way i can avoid these escape sequences and have regular data?

Comment: Can you please reformat this question? What is the exact text of that row in the .csv file (it's unusual for .csv files to have square braces and single quotes)?  What is the exact output you're currently getting, and what is the desired output?

Comment: I'm running a preprocessor that tokenizes tweets and saves them in square brackets in a csv file. The issue is, while tweeting some people do 'yes' while some do "yes" 
if they write 'yes', twitter sends the data as " 'yes' " otherwise as ' "yes" '

so both the types of words are getting saved.

some with single quotes and some with double.

while importing to a list, python is automatically adding an escape to the single quotes which is causing issues with my classification algorithm. So was wondering if i can normalize all the quotes

Comment: Double quoted strings are in csv spec. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180   Single quotes cause trouble for csv.reader()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python 2.x:

```
corpus=str([rows[0].translate(None,"'[]\"").split(",") for rows in csvReader1])
```

For python 3.x:

```
corpus=str([rows[0].translate({ord(i):None for i in "'[]\""}).split(",") for rows in csvReader1])
```

Comment: i've added a comment to my question. Can you please see that and help me out?

Comment: This should take the output you're getting with the escape characters and fix the quotes for you

Comment: after this, now if I do `x=vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()` i get the error `return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' `

Comment: Well that's because it's a list. What output are you looking for? A string?

Comment: Ok, you really didn't give a lot of info... I'll edit again

Comment: with your code im getting `['@odaxxxel', ' thing', ' multipl', ' colleg', ' friend', ' page', ' dont', ' go', ' harvard']`  while i actually want `"['@odaxxxel', ' thing', ' multipl', ' colleg', ' friend', ' page', ' dont', ' go', ' harvard']"`

Comment: See if this works for you. Probably not the prettiest but I'm still not quite sure what your input is and I have to go

Comment: What i basically want is "['hi', 'hello']" i want the box bracket inside quotes

Comment: Yeah, that's what the current version should give you. Did it work?

Comment: No it didn't work. The current code is converting it to a string object, but not putting quotes around the box bracket

Comment: getting this error with current code: `ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.`

Comment: Alright well based on the information you provided in the question I think this answers it. If you're actually looking for something different you need to edit your question to include these details. Include a sample of your full input, your desired output, and any code you've written to get there. It sounds like what you actually want is to run vectorize.fit_transform on some data, but you haven't given any info about this.